# PHP MYSQL Hyperlinks and Forms again

Tags: php, mysql

Guys, am not having much luck...and I've tried and tried. Have included the code below. Am doing this in Dreamweaver hence the funny code. This is the edit page. I successfully parsed 'bet_id' value from Page 1 to this page. It populates the form fields with the correct 'bet_id' and 'category_id' values based on the value parsed from page 1. Problem comes to when I update the values in the form. If I update the 'category_id' value and hit the Update bet button, the script does not update the bet record in my database. Any help much appreciated.

```
<?php require_once('../Connections/punters_c.php'); ?>
<?php
mysql_select_db($database_punters_c, $punters_c);

$query_Recordset1       = "SELECT bet_id, punter_id,category_id FROM betslip where bet_id =".intval($_REQUEST['bet_id']);
$Recordset1             = mysql_query($query_Recordset1, $punters_c) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset1         = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1);
$totalRows_Recordset1   = mysql_num_rows($Recordset1);


##the below function removes dodgy field values

function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  $theValue = (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) ? addslashes($theValue) : $theValue;

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . doubleval($theValue) . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}
?>
<?
                // edit.php
if ((isset($_POST["apply"])) && ($_POST["apply"] == "update_betslip_detail")){

        $query = sprintf("  UPDATE betslip 
                            SET category_id = '%d' 
                            WHERE bet_id = %d", 
                            mysql_real_escape($_POST['category_id']),
                            mysql_real_escape($_POST['bet_id'])
                                                                );

  mysql_select_db($database_punters_c, $punters_c);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($query, $punters_c) or die('Connection error to MYSQL occurred: '.(mysql_error()));

        header("Location: /update_betslip_test.php");

    }
    else 
    {
        echo "bet detail not updated";
    }
    ?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="update_betslip_detail">

    <input type="text"      name="bet id"       id = "bet_id"       value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['bet_id']; ?>"/>
    <input type="text"      name="category_id"  id = "category_id"  value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['category_id']; ?>"/>


    <input type="hidden"    name= "apply"       value="update_betslip_detail"/>

    <input type="submit"    value="Update bet"/>
    </form>

    <p><a href="update_betslip_test.php">Back to Update page </a></p>
</body></html>
<?php
mysql_free_result($Recordset1);
?>
```

Comment: you should really tidy this up, its barley readable

Comment: Youre right. Sorry. 

I am using a hyperlink on a bet_id field in a record table from page 1 to bring up the details of the record (bet_id and category_id) in a form in page 2. I want these form fields to be editable fields which the user can alter/update in the database by clicking the Update bet button. Hope that makes more sense.

Comment: Should also confirm that it is just the update to the database part which I'm having trouble with.

Answer (score 0):

First, there is no function called `mysql_real_escape()` so calling it should give you a fatal error (unless that's something you've defined yourself).  Also: since you're using `sprintf(..., '%d')`, using `mysql_real_escape_string()` (the correct function for escaping strings) is not necessary.

Related note (but not connected to your original problem): you should not be using `addslashes()` up in your `GetSQLValueString()` function.  That too should be `mysql_real_escape_string()`.  Just calling `addslashes()` will work for legitimate input (e.g., turn `O'Brien` into `O\'Brien`) but will not work for certain types of malicious input.